# Make a car drive perpendicular to normals on certain surfaces given certain conditionsin BGE

Tags: game-engine, physics, normals, logic-bricks

What I have in mind is to make a car I made (using the car physics, the one with the rigid body and non-solid wheels) be able to drive up steep surfaces and go around loops and corkscrews and other things in the track I made if it goes a certain speed or higher.

I'm guessing this will require being able to orient the car to the normals of the part of the track that I want to have it run up on, but how can I do this with the criterion that my car has to go a certain speed or faster to stick?

Comment: When you are talking about the vehicle wrapper, this is not possible. The wheels are "measured" along -Z. This means looping is impossible with it.

Comment: I'm guessing that the vehicle wrapper orients the wheels to -Z global. Could it not be changed to orient the wheels to the -Z local of an object via Python?